# Start With and End With Regex

Tags: regex

I have the rows listed below.

```
remove product 100 unit replace with 200
Remove Product 100 unit Replace 200
Remove 100 unit Replace with a 200
remove product 100 unit replace with an 200
remove product2 100 unit replace with an 200
```

I have attempted the regex below, with no luck.

```
/([remove 100|remove Product 100](.*?)[replace with 200|replace with a 200|replace with an 200])/i
```

It should flag the first four results, but not the last as its product2.

It flags everything on regexr. Example can be seen here: http://regexr.com/396u3

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: What are you trying to capture?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Apparently the word `unit`.

Comment: My apologies. I'm not trying to capture any word. I just want to check if the line matches the regex criteria. The above lines are notes and I want to check if 'product 100' requires removing and replacing with product 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/remove (?:product )?100(.*?)replace (?:with )?(?:an? )?200/gi
```

The above expression is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex would be,

```
^remove (?:product ?)?100 (\S+) (?:replace (?:with )?(?:an |a )?200)$
```

This would capture only the string `unit` in  the first 4 lines.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hN3iE2/4)

Comment: Please read the question again: __It should flag the first four results, but *not the last as its `product2`*.__

Comment: @hjpotter92 updated. Didn't see that. He says just the string `unit`, so i write the code for all the 5 lines.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that you are creating a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

```
[remove 100|remove Product 100]
```

instead of an [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

```
(remove 100|remove Product 100)
```

The character class matches only one character out of the character between the square brackets. So if you change your regex to

```
/((remove 100|remove Product 100)(.*?)(replace with 200|replace with a 200|replace with an 200))/i
```

it will match far better.